# Weird update issue with v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, v-model

I am working on sort of dynamic input fields. Based on entries in an array I would like to generate a textarea with a corresponding `v-model` attribute. For some reason, the value of the `v-model` get's only updated when I type something in another input field.

So first, I retrieve an array with `languages`. Then I will use a foreach function to add a new property for each child called `er`. I will set the result to an array which I use to display the input fields.

JS

```
getLanguages() {
    const headers = this.headers;
    axios.get(`${this.$API_URL}/api/v1/settings/languages`, { headers }).then(response => {
        const { data } = response.data;
        this.languages = data;
        this.setQuestions();
    });
},

setQuestions() {
    const languages = this.languages;
    const questions = this.question.questions;

    languages.forEach(item => questions.push(item));

    questions.map(item => {
        item.er = null;
        return item;
    });

    this.question.questions = questions;

    this.loaded = true;
},
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group row" v-for="option in question.questions" :key="option.id">
    <label for="question_name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label label">{{ t('Question') }} {{ option.name }} </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea  id="question_name" v-model="option.er" required></textarea>
        {{ option.er }}
    </div>
</div>
```

So the main problem I'm having is that the property `er` is not in sync with the input field. When I type something in another input with a v-model property of the same object but not the same property the value get's updated. Is there something I am not seeing?

Comment: MDN Array.prototype.map():
The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.
you don't store the array created from `map` method anywhere so actually map does nothing in your code.

Answer (score 2):

After diving into the Vue API docs I came across this little friend:

`this.$set`

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set

"Adds a property to a reactive object, ensuring the new property is also reactive, so triggers view updates."

New JS

```
setQuestions() {
    const languages = this.languages;
    const questions = this.question.questions;

    languages.forEach(item => questions.push(item));

    questions.map(item => {
        this.$set(item, 'er', null);
    });

    this.question.questions = questions;

    this.loaded = true;
},
```

Answer (score -1):

I see this issue is related to reactivity in depth .

if you assign data instead of

> this.language = data;

to

> this.language = Object.assign({}, this.language , data)

check this link in more detail

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html